# Use VTTCue Object on Angular2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I want to load subtitles dynamically on a video.

```
    let subs:TextTrack = video.addTextTrack('subtitles');

    for (let dataSrt of dataSrts) {
        let cue: any = new VTTCue(
            dataSrt['startTime'],
            dataSrt['endTime'],
            dataSrt['text']
        );

        subs.addCue(cue);
    }

    subs.mode = "showing";
```

This actually works just fine but the compiler doesn't seem to know the VTTCue Object.

There is a TextTrackCue Object but it currently doesn't work on any browser.

The problem is that when I launch the server with npm start, an error block the launch but if I change the code after it's launched everything works just fine.

I tried adding an empty VTTCue class (cpp style) but typescript doesn't like it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an object without Typescript complaining about existence of properties, you can cast it as any, and since VTTCue should be present on the window object, you can do the following:

```
let cue: any = new (<any>window).VTTCue(...);
```

Or using TSX syntax (as `<>` is now reserved for JSX) :

```
let cue: any = new (window as any).VTTCue(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to a [videogular2 demo](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2-showroom/blob/master/src/app/cue-points-player/cue-points-player.component.ts) we can do the following:

```
declare var VTTCue;
```

Have this working in one of my projects.
The only drawback is that I can't use this symbol when defining member types, but I am able to use the constructor VTTCue(...).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a VTTCue class, try making it a VTTCue interface, like the following:

```
interface VTTCue {
  new(start: number, end: number, cueText: string): VTTCue
}
```

Comment: Pretty smart but unfortunately I still get an error from angular.
"'VTTCue' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it with TypeScript v2.32:

```
declare var VTTCue: {
  prototype: TextTrackCue;
  new(startTime: number, endTime: number, text: string): TextTrackCue;
};
```

I just copied the TextTrackCue definition from here and renamed it.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts